# Safari border bug

Tags: css, safari, border

I need to make blockquote left border with gradient. But in Safari it displays on both sides. I have tried to make border-right 0 and none. Also I have tried to use -webkit- prefix.

This is how it looks on Safari:
[image: safari]
And Chrome: 
[image: chrome]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/domanskyi/pen/xewQNb

HTML:

```
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nam itaque nesciunt omnis, ut nihil veritatis adipisci corrupti velit. Reiciendis dolorem suscipit numquam expedita iure eum labore eos maxime rerum.</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
}

.content {
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;  

  border-left-style: solid;
  -webkit-border-left-style: solid;

  border-width: 0 0 0 3px;
  -webkit-border-width: 0 0 0 3px;

  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #D71F49 0%, #2E3D59 100%) 1 100%;

  border-right-width: 0px !important;
  -webkit-border-right-width: 0px !important;

  border-right: 0px !important;
  -webkit-border-right: 0px !important;

  border-right: none !important;
  -webkit-border-right: none !important;

  border-image-repeat: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I`ve gave up and made it with pseudo-class)

```
.content2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;    
}

.content2::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #D71F49 0%, #2E3D59 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with your code but it simplifying it dramatically got it working the same in Safari for me: https://codepen.io/RwwL/pen/JVYzox

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
}

.content {
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;    
  border-width: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #D71F49 0%, #2E3D59 100%) 1 100%;
  border-image-repeat: none;
}
```

Comment: Hm, is this working ok without   border-style: solid? Because Chrome don`t render border without this property.

Comment: I saw that too. But adding border-style: solid above the border-width rule seems to have got it working consistently in Chrome/Safari/Firefox. Sorry, can't fire up VMs to check IE/Edge right now.